# Error on running Grails project

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-boot

I have a problem with grailsVersion=3.3.0.M1 and gradleWrapperVersion=3.0. Whenever I run the project I get the following error.

> |Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
>
> CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 13.543 secs |Running application... 2017-05-29
>   22:08:46.634 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application startup failed
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean  at
>   asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure1.doCall(AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin.groovy:105)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)    at
>   grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:759)
>     at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)    at
>   grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531)  at
>   org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:167)
>     at
>   grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>     at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at mjmdashboardnext.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 33 common
>   frames omitted
>
> 2017-05-29 22:08:46.749 ERROR --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with
>   name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the
>   context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64c2b546:
>   startup date [Mon May 29 22:08:08 NPT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
>     at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at mjmdashboardnext.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
>
> 2017-05-29 22:08:46.765 ERROR --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with
>   name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
>   threw an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not
>   initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the
>   context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64c2b546:
>   startup date [Mon May 29 22:08:08 NPT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
>     at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)   at
>   grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at mjmdashboardnext.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error | Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried to upgrade my plugins in build.gradle but the error remains the same.

My build.gradle is as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.7"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.5"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.10.1'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.0"
    } }

version "0.5.1" group "test"

apply plugin:"eclipse" apply plugin:"idea" apply plugin:"war" apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web" apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs' } }

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false }

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.2.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.2.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.2.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates:1.2.1"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:aws-sdk-s3:2.1.5'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"

    compile 'com.nayidisha.grails.uploadr:grails3-uploadr:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:joda-time:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.9'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:wkhtmltopdf:1.0.0.RC7'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:rabbitmq:2.0.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:excel-import:3.0.0.RC2'
    compile 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:selfie:1.1.1'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc-grails3:0.26.0"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"


}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always') }

grails {
    pathingJar = true }
```

Has anyone faced this issue? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
```

Is not compatible with 3.3 - use

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1'
```

Also I'd suggest using the gradle wrapper that the grails version you use ships with. 3.0 is quite old.

You can see my 3.3.0 Upgrade notes here https://gist.github.com/erichelgeson/72e1b6cb8e1b9428738799368c32133f

Also 3.3.0.M2 was just released today with a bunch of fixes.